# Python import module from relative folder

Tags: python

i'm creating a python program, and i want to split it up into seperate files. I'm using import to do this, but its not working (specifically, a variable is stored in one python file, and its not being read by the main one.

```
program /

     main.py

     lib /

          __init__.py

          config.py

          functions.py
```

I have in main.py:

```
import lib.config
import lib.functions
print(main)
```

and config.py has

```
 main = "hello"
```

I should be getting the output "hello", when i'm executing the file main.py, but i'm not. I have the same problem with functions stored in functions.py

Any help would be great,

Comment: `print(lib.config.main)`?

Comment: Have you imported these two files in `__init__.py`?

Comment: @solusipse: that is not required at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importing the module with a simple `import` statement does *not* copy the names from that module into your own global namespace.

Either refer to the `main` name through attribute access:

```
print(lib.config.main)
```

or use the `from ... import ...` syntax:

```
from lib.config import main
```

instead.

You can learn more about how importing works in the [Modules section of the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html).

Comment: Got it. I just user from lib.config import * so that i got everything